# Kubectl: get a shell to a running container under Windows

Tags: windows, shell, kubectl

I'm trying to log into running container using Kubectl, according to instructions in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/, but I'm failing miserably:

```
kubectl exec -it mycontainer -- /bin/bash
```

> Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of
>   file rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed:
>   container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"D:/Applications/Git/usr/bin/bash\": stat
>   D:/Applications/Git/usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory"
>
> command terminated with exit code 126

It looks like kubectl tries to exec bash on my machine, which is totally not what I want to achieve.

I can exec commands without spaces:

```
$ kubectl exec mycontainer 'ls'
lib
start.sh
```

But with not:

```
$ kubectl exec mycontainer 'ls .'
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls .\": executable file not found in $PATH"

command terminated with exit code 126
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I've tried both in mingw git shell , as with plain windows console.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems it might be related to this github [issue.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37471)

One of the workarounds might be to use winpty as specified [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2271#issuecomment-317006437).
`winpty kubectl.exe exec -it pod-name -- sh`

You can also try `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` it worked for me, but I do not have a Windows machine to check it in the same environment as you.

Comment: Note, `/bin/sh` isn't better, be it with bash for windows or windows' `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

Below command worked for me to launch windows command prompt

kubectl exec -it mycontainer -- cmd.exe